# Group Logic app action/connectors in log analytics if failed run

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

Hi i'm trying to set up som kind of basic logging using logic apps in conjunction with log analytics. When searching for a failed run by runID i get the data for every singel action, skipped, failed succeeded and so on, of that run.

Is there any way to write a query of some sort to group all the actions to one useful record containing the necessary data for each action but also custom tracked properties (that i track using a compose in the workflow)?

anyone done something similar before?

I want to use this record later to be able to set alarms in azure monitoring.

What i am doing right now for example is searching after a specific workflow run by doing this:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where resource_workflowName_s =="[Logic App Name]"
| where resource_runId_s == "[RUN_ID]"
```

And i get a result of all the actions, skipped succeeded, failed and what not.

I only want 1 record with the necessary information for the failed run so to speak.

UPDATE:

so i was looking ab it on the OMS which the logic app is connected to, and i almost managed to get what i wanted by the default query OMS generates, what i am missing is the tracked values per run, on failed runs.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "WorkflowRuntime"
| where OperationName == "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/workflowRunCompleted"
| join kind= rightouter
(
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "WorkflowRuntime"
| where OperationName == "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/workflowRunStarted"
| join kind= inner
(
    AzureDiagnostics
    | where Category == "WorkflowRuntime"
    | where OperationName == "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/workflowTriggerCompleted"
    | project TriggerName = Resource, resource_runId_s
)
on resource_runId_s
| project WorkflowStartStatus=status_s, 
WorkflowNameFromInnerQuery=resource_workflowName_s, 
WorkflowIdFromInnerQuery=workflowId_s, 
ResourceGroupFromInnerQuery=resource_resourceGroupName_s, 
RunIdFromInnerQuery = resource_runId_s, OriginRunIdFromInnerQuery = 
resource_originRunId_s, TrackingIdFromInnerQuery = 
correlation_clientTrackingId_s, StartTimeFromInnerQuery = startTime_t, 
resource_runId_s, TriggerName
)
on resource_runId_s
| extend WorkflowStatus=iff(isnotempty(status_s), status_s, 
WorkflowStartStatus)
| extend WorkflowName=iff(isnotempty(resource_workflowName_s), 
resource_workflowName_s, WorkflowNameFromInnerQuery)
| extend WorkflowId=iff(isnotempty(workflowId_s), workflowId_s, 
WorkflowIdFromInnerQuery)
| extend ResourceGroup=iff(isnotempty(resource_resourceGroupName_s), 
resource_resourceGroupName_s, ResourceGroupFromInnerQuery)
| extend RunId=iff(isnotempty(resource_runId_s), resource_runId_s, 
RunIdFromInnerQuery)
| extend OriginRunId=iff(isnotempty(resource_originRunId_s), 
resource_originRunId_s, OriginRunIdFromInnerQuery)
| extend TrackingId=iff(isnotempty(correlation_clientTrackingId_s), 
correlation_clientTrackingId_s, TrackingIdFromInnerQuery)
| extend StartTime=iff(isnotempty(startTime_t), startTime_t, 
StartTimeFromInnerQuery)
| extend EndTime=endTime_t
| extend Duration=iff(isnotempty(EndTime), todouble(EndTime - StartTime) / 
10000000, double(null))
| where WorkflowId == "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/B405FEEE-D8DA-484B-8285-4399B07EFFCA/RESOURCEGROUPS/INTEGRATION_RG_TEST/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.LOGIC/WORKF
LOWS/RABE_REST_CARUS_V2"
| project WorkflowName, WorkflowId, WorkflowStatus, Duration, ResourceGroup, 
TrackingId, RunId, StartTime, EndTime, TriggerName
| top 10001 by RunId asc`enter code here`
| where WorkflowStatus == "Failed"
```